# Book series - well over 15-18 books with flying eagles (birds) in it

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a series in the late 70's and early 80's that had flying birds that were large (like large eagles).  This series was well over 15 books maybe even over 20.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: I pulled identifying info out of your post. Were the birds the main characters? Pets to the main characters? Antagonists? Common wildlife? What sort of things did they get up to? Was it about survival in nature? Pitched warfare? Magical shenanigans? And what aspects of the book are fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: Please define "large". Large like on the large end of the spectrum for real-world eagles, or "large" like people ride them like they were flying horses?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [the Gor books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gor) by John Norman. it's up to 30+ now. Were there slave-girls? The birds were called Tarns.

Comment: Going by the little information posted, that was  my first thought, too.

Comment: Same here, do a Google image search for "Gor Books".  (I quit after about 6 or 7.  I once heard someone say that the first 5 books could have been edited down to a decent trilogy.)

Comment: Sounds like it. If so, this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39395/man-from-earth-kidnapped-to-less-advanced-sister-planet-where-he-fights-and-ride

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether "large eagles" are on the large end for real-world eagles, or "large" like able to carry a human rider:

One possible match is the [Vlad Taltos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Brust#Vlad_Taltos) series, by Steven Brust, includes a couple of flying reptiles that are fairly large (but not too large to ride on the shoulders of the main characters). The reptiles are called *jhereg*.

The first book came out in 1983 (so, maybe a bit too new for a match). There are 15 books in this series, plus at least 5 related books set in the same world, but well before the protagonist's birth.